# Aplicacion en Laravel no detecta los cambios realizados al codigo

Tags: laravel-5, git

[image]
Tengo un problema al correr la aplicacion laravel 5.6 que desarrollo, como se puede ver en la primera imagen dice que existe el campo id en la DB, y que ademas muestra la linea de codigo que da el error, y como se puede ver la linea 73 tiene $proyecto->id = $titulo, ese es el error en realidad ya que la DB tiene como campo pk proyecto_id, no id.

[image]
Ahora bien en esta segunda imagen pueden ver el codigo real que tengo con algunos cambios, entre ellos la linea 75 que ya tiene el campo real. pero cuando corro la aplicacion como ven la corre con el otro codigo, el aclaro que esta segunda imagen es de mi propia rama ya que usamos git como control de versiones y corro el proyecto usando laragon y en la consola de laragon estoy posicionado en mi rama(git checkout mirama) y el codigo que aparece en la primera imagen es de la rama master, el modelo proyecto tiene su respectivo $primaryKey con el valor correcto, tambien no usamos migraciones en este proyecto, la DB ya estaba creada, entonces no se si alguien puede ayudarme diciendome por que se da este problema y como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Imagino TroyPerez que también el campo proyecto_id lo has incluido en el array $fillable dentro del Modelo $proyecto.

Comment: no lo habia incluido, quizas me imagine que con poner primaryKey bastaba jeje, acabo de hacer lo que dijiste y si me resolvio el problema, gracias por la ayuda Manuel Roca.